# Bluetooth range problem

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Pavilion ab030tx. When I use Windows, I don't face any problem with my Bluetooth range, but coming to Ubuntu I have to keep my Bluetooth speaker very close to my laptop for it to work without breaking the voice. Here is the screen-shot of execution of this command:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`

[image]

My bluetooth pairs and connects without any problem.